# GraphQL: How to implement a GraphQLList of GraphQLObjectTypes

Tags: graphql, relay, graphql-js

I have an issue with GraphQL (Specifically, implementing GraphQLList)

I have a query `getItemByName` that correctly returns an `Item`, with Type `itemType`. But I haven't been able to implement a `getItemList` (Or a proper example btw). I know that it's supposed to have a type that implements GraphQLList.

But am i doing it right? What's the data format that `resolve` should recieve? (Or that `getItems()` should return). An array of objects? Should those objects be implementing "itemType" definition? Should an interface be implemented?

```js
export const itemType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Item',
  fields: {
    name: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'Item Name',
    },
  },
});

const itemListType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'ItemsList',
  fields: {
    items: {
      type: new GraphQLList(itemType),
      description: 'List of items',
    },
  },
});

{...}

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: new GraphQLObjectType({
        name: 'Query',
        fields: {
           itemList: {
               type: itemListType,
               resolve: () => getItems(),
           }
        }
    })
})
```

As it is now, the query:

```
itemList {
  items {
    name
  }
}
```

its returning:

```
{
  "data": {
    "itemList": {
      "items": null
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is really really welcome! :D

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll first explain the root cause of your problem. Then I'll discuss how GraphQLList is generally used.

In your schema query, `itemList` field is of type `itemListType`. Now this `itemListType` has a field `items`.  Therefore, the query's `itemList` field must be resolved to an object which has an `items` field. But the `getItems()` function returns an array or a promised array and does not have field `items`. That's why you're getting `"items": null` in the query response.

Now about the confusion around GraphQLList: if it's just a list, there's actually no need to define a separate GraphQL type for that. In your query, you include a field with type GraphQLList of item type:

```
const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: new GraphQLObjectType({
        name: 'Query',
        fields: {
           itemList: {
               type: new GraphQLList(itemType),
               resolve: () => getItems(),
           }
        }
    })
});
```

If your list is not that simple, for instance, `itemList` actually has two fields(oldItems, newItems - both are lists), you should define a separate type. Remember to modify the resolve function accordingly:

```
itemList: {
  type: itemListType,
  resolve: () => {
    // get new items
    // get old items
    return {
      newItems, 
      oldItems
    };
  },
},
```

(By the way, your code has some syntax errors like itemsList, itemList, itemsListType, itemListType. I have edited your question. The changes will appear after my edit is approved.)

Answer (score 1):

`getItems()` should return an array of itemType objects (or a promise for one). What those itemTypes look like is up to you. They'll simply be passed to the `resolve` function of the fields that you asked for in `itemType`.

Comment: It is actually a promise.
But when you say an array of itemType. Do i need to transform them in some way? or just with an array of objects that has a `name` property  i.e. ```[{name: 'asd'}]```

Comment: The objects in the array can be whatever you want, so `{name: 'asd'}` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue.
It was not a problem with the structure of data that I was returning, it was the way i was defining a the query.

```
export const coworkList = {
  name: 'coworkList',
  description: 'Returns a list (up until 10) of coworks',
  type:  new GraphQLList(coworkType),
  resolve: () => getCoworks(),
};
```

The `coworkList`query definition is that is now being passed into the schema.
Works great!
const schema = new GraphQL

```
Schema({
  query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: () => ({
      coworkList,
      coworkByName,
      coworkById,
    }),
  }),
});
```